# How to allow users to download images from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My google app engine app allows users to upload images to Google Cloud Storage.  I use python on the server.

What is the easiest way to allow users to download the images stored in Google Cloud Storage with program. Javascript on the client side bars users from saving downloaded files.

The python `boto` library seems like overkill. I would like to display a list of images a user is allowed to download, with a 'download' button beside it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever logic your app uses to determine which images the currently logged-in user is allowed to download, you just need to put on each corresponding "download button" a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs) for the image within (assuming HTML5) an `<a href=[[signed url] download=[[filename]]>[[image name/description]]<a>` tag.

Comment: Or request a download for a user selected image. Example: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url